# How to use viewport-relative sized typography without breaking vertical rhythm?

Tags: typography, css

For quite a while now, I've been using a baseline grid in my webdesign. I really value the vertical rhythm, with the typography's baselines alingning with the design elements and each other. Up till now, I've been using `em`s and `px` as my units.

Now I've discovered the existence of the viewport-related units `vw`, `vh` and `vmin`, I'd like to start using those as font sizes. I am at a loss, however, how I'd use `vw` as font size unit, while still having it obey my baseline grid at every possible viewport size.

What is an effective way to combine viewport-related units and a baseline grid in webdesign?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web coding and belongs on StackOverflow.com

Comment: While I do agree it would also suite Stack I think this question can stay in scope when someone is designing in the browser.

Comment: Consider that users don't necessarily want the font sizes to change as they resize their browser.

Comment: Don't use viewport units for type almost always. It's better to use `em` and `rem` in combination with media queries